# Trouble with union and grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this has been a topic here before but I'm still having trouble grouping within unions. I've looked here: [Grouping and Joining a Unioned Table. Having Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436459/grouping-and-joining-a-unioned-table-having-problems) among others and am still confused as to what to do with the parenthesis. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      sum(sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS)"Reg Hours",
      sum(sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS)"OT Hours"
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS"Reg Hours",
      sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS"OT Hours"
    FROM
      SA_WORK_ORDER W,
      SA_WORK_ORDER_TASK WT,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD2,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD3,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD4,
      smu_transactions sm
    WHERE
      SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND W.WORK_ORDER_NO         = WT.WORK_ORDER_NO
    AND
      (
        WT.WORK_ORDER_NO        = SD.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND WT.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO = SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd2.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd2.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd3.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd3.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd4.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd4.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY  = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd.attribute_desc          = 'Type of Outage'
    AND SD2.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd2.attribute_desc         = 'Total Time Water Off'
    AND SD3.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd3.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Homes affected'
    AND SD4.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd4.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Businesses affected'
    AND WT.TASK_STATUS            != 'CANCELED'
    AND sm.transaction_type        = 'CT'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      SUM(sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS)"Reg Hours",
      SUM(sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS)"OT Hours"
    FROM
    (  SELECT
        W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
        W.WORK_CLASS,
        SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
        sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
        sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
        WT.TASK_STATUS,
        wt.area,
        wt.creation_date,
        sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
        sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
        sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS"Reg Hours",
        sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS"OT Hours"
    FROM
      SA_WORK_HISTORY W,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_TASK WT,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD2,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD3,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD4,
      smu_transactions sm
    WHERE
      SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND W.WORK_ORDER_NO         = WT.WORK_ORDER_NO
    AND
      (
        WT.WORK_ORDER_NO        = SD.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND WT.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO = SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd2.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd2.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd3.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd3.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd4.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd4.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sm.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sm.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY  = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd.attribute_desc          = 'Type of Outage'
    AND SD2.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd2.attribute_desc         = 'Total Time Water Off'
    AND SD3.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd3.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Homes affected'
    AND SD4.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd4.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Businesses affected'
    AND WT.TASK_STATUS            != 'CANCELED'
    AND sm.transaction_type        = 'CT'
    )
    GROUP BY
      sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS,
      sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS
      ORDER BY
      sd.work_order_no,
      sd.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO;
```

The error is:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 152 Column: 23

I've tried many different permutations of the parenthesis locations and understand how it should work but I still can't seem to grasp where to put them (or if that is the problem at all).

TIA for any help you can give!

Comment: You need to have an end parenthesis prior to the `UNION ALL`.  Once you fix this, your referencing of columns needs work (referring to aliases which are encapsulated in a derived table).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, by the referencing of columns you're speaking of the end group by and order by?

Comment: For example, `W.WORK_ORDER_NO` (query block one), should either be prefixed by the name of the derived table which it is coming from (but you have not assigned one) or with no qualification (because everything is coming from your derived table).

Comment: By the way, do yourself a favor and use a tool (e.g. a good text editor) or development tool which detects these pairings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your query to arrive at this pseudo query and the missing paranthesis was immediately apparent.

```
SELECT
  set_of_rows
FROM
(
SELECT
 set_of_rows
FROM
  set_of_tables
WHERE
  set_of_conditions ) //You missed this closing paranthesis
                    ^
UNION ALL

SELECT
  set_of_rows
FROM
(  SELECT
    set_of_rows
FROM
  set_of_tables
WHERE
  set_of_conditions
)
GROUP BY
  some_rows
ORDER BY
  some_other_rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really want, but there were some errors about grouping by and also I added a new right parenthesis, fixed query:

```
SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      sum(sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS)"Reg Hours",
      sum(sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS)"OT Hours"
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS"Reg Hours",
      sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS"OT Hours"
    FROM
      SA_WORK_ORDER W,
      SA_WORK_ORDER_TASK WT,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD2,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD3,
      SA_SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAILS SD4,
      smu_transactions sm
    WHERE
      SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND W.WORK_ORDER_NO         = WT.WORK_ORDER_NO
    AND
      (
        WT.WORK_ORDER_NO        = SD.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND WT.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO = SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd2.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd2.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd3.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd3.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd4.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd4.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY  = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd.attribute_desc          = 'Type of Outage'
    AND SD2.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd2.attribute_desc         = 'Total Time Water Off'
    AND SD3.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd3.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Homes affected'
    AND SD4.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd4.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Businesses affected'
    AND WT.TASK_STATUS            != 'CANCELED'
    AND sm.transaction_type        = 'CT'
    )
    group by 
    W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
      SUM(sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS)"Reg Hours",
      SUM(sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS)"OT Hours"
    FROM
    (  SELECT
        W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
        W.WORK_CLASS,
        SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
        sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
        sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
        WT.TASK_STATUS,
        wt.area,
        wt.creation_date,
        sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
        sd4.attribute_value"Businesses Affected",
        sm.CT_REGULAR_HOURS"Reg Hours",
        sm.CT_PREMIUM_HOURS"OT Hours"
    FROM
      SA_WORK_HISTORY W,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_TASK WT,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD2,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD3,
      SA_WORK_HISTORY_SERVICE_DETAIL SD4,
      smu_transactions sm
    WHERE
      SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND W.WORK_ORDER_NO         = WT.WORK_ORDER_NO
    AND
      (
        WT.WORK_ORDER_NO        = SD.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND WT.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO = SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd2.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd2.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd3.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd3.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sd4.work_order_no
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sd4.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND
      (
        sd.work_order_no        = sm.WORK_ORDER_NO
      AND sd.work_order_task_no = sm.work_order_task_no
      )
    AND SD.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY  = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd.attribute_desc          = 'Type of Outage'
    AND SD2.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd2.attribute_desc         = 'Total Time Water Off'
    AND SD3.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd3.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Homes affected'
    AND SD4.SPECIFICATION_CATEGORY = 'WATER OUTAGE'
    AND sd4.attribute_desc         = 'Number of Businesses affected'
    AND WT.TASK_STATUS            != 'CANCELED'
    AND sm.transaction_type        = 'CT'
    )
    GROUP BY
      W.WORK_ORDER_NO,
      W.WORK_CLASS,
      SD.WORK_ORDER_TASK_NO,
      sd.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE"Outage Type",
      sd2.attribute_value"Total Time Water Off",
      WT.TASK_STATUS,
      wt.area,
      wt.creation_date,
      sd3.attribute_value"Homes Affected",
      sd4.attribute_value
      ORDER BY 11, 12;
```